# Software Updater problem in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, update-manager

This is the error I'm getting:

```
W:GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D1106511179518B2, 
W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_main_source_Sources
 Hash Sum mismatch
W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_mozillateam_firefox-next_ubuntu_dists_quantal_main_binary-i386_Packages
 Hash Sum mismatch
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and execute the following commands one by one.

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com D1106511179518B2
sudo find /var/lib/apt/lists/ -type f -delete
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [kioskea.net](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/809-debian-apt-get-no-pubkey-gpg-error):

> Simply type the following commands, taking care to replace the number below with that of the key that was displayed in the error message:
>
> ```
> gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  010908312D230C5F      
> gpg -a --export 010908312D230C5F | sudo apt-key add -
> ```

You would replace `pgpkeys.mit.edu` with the PPA URL and you would replace the alpha-numerical key with `D1106511179518B2`.